# Replace an element in OMUMap(IBM Rational Rhapsody )

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rhapsody

I want to overwrite an element corresponding to an key with new value.
What function I can use for this?

I tried by calling fun

```
myMap.add(key, value)
```

But this is not replacing the value already stored in map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add()` should work, here is an example:

```
OMUMap myMap;
char key1[] = "key-1";
char key2[] = "key-2";

/* initialize map */
myMap.add(static_cast<void*>(key1), static_cast<void*>("foo"));
myMap.add(static_cast<void*>(key2), static_cast<void*>("bar"));

std::cout << key1 << ": " << static_cast<char*>(myMap.getAt(key1)) << std::endl;
std::cout << key2 << ": " << static_cast<char*>(myMap.getAt(key2)) << std::endl;

/* replace 'key-1' value */                    
myMap.add(static_cast<void*>(key1), static_cast<void*>("bazzz"));

std::cout << key1 << ": " << static_cast<char*>(myMap.getAt(key1)) << std::endl;
std::cout << key2 << ": " << static_cast<char*>(myMap.getAt(key2)) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
key-1: foo
key-2: bar
key-1: bazzz
key-2: bar
```